# Getting the greatest "dauer" entry from a table created by a query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I know this is a common problem with SQL and I've already found a lot of explanations on how to do this, but I just can't figure out how to do when the table I want to get the max entry (for `dauer`) from a table that is already created by a query.

I am using a SQL Server database. I am really hoping you guys can give me a hint on that.

```
SELECT 
    foo.vname, foo.nname, foo.sw_name,  
    SUM(foo.dauer) AS dauer 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         benutzer.vname, benutzer.nname, verwendung.sw_name, verwendung.dauer
     FROM 
         benutzer 
     INNER JOIN 
         verwendung ON benutzer.login = verwendung.login 
                    AND benutzer.pw = verwendung.pw
     GROUP BY 
         benutzer.login, benutzer.pw, verwendung.sw_name, verwendung.dauer
     ORDER BY 
         benutzer.vname ASC, benutzer.nname ASC, verwendung.sw_name ASC) AS foo
GROUP BY 
    foo.vname, foo.nname, foo.sw_name
```

EDIT: Clarification of what I want to know

I want to get those entries of the table which have the max value in the `dauer` column.

For example:

For Ada should be Ada - Lovelace - Presmaker - 910

[image: Table from my query]

Comment: Hello @Florian Drucker, please can you update your question with the database that you use ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBokšić done- as far as possible since the "verwendung" table is pretty big

Comment: Hello @Florian Drucker, sorry, my explanation was bad. You do not need to update this images. You can delete them, the first one is enough. All I wanted to ask is: Do you use Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer or some other database. I ask because the code is different in every one of them. Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you need `SUM(foo.dauer)` or `MAX(foo.dauer)` ?

Comment: Okey done.
I needed the sum before getting the max since there are multiple entries that needed to be summed up

Comment: So this image that is in the question is the result with the SUM and now from this query you need to get vname, nname, sw_name and max (foo.dauer) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand what you need and if I am right this will do it:
As you say :

> I want to get the max entry(for "dauer") from a table that is already
>   created by a query

```
select foo2.vname
       , foo2.nname
       , foo2.sw_name
       , foo2.dauer 
from (
      SELECT foo.vname
             , foo.nname
             , foo.sw_name
             ,  SUM(foo.dauer) AS dauer 
      from (SELECT benutzer.vname
                   , benutzer.nname
                   , verwendung.sw_name
                   , verwendung.dauer
            FROM benutzer 
            INNER JOIN verwendung 
            ON benutzer.login = verwendung.login 
               AND benutzer.pw = verwendung.pw
            GROUP BY benutzer.login
                     , benutzer.pw
                     , verwendung.sw_name
                     , verwendung.dauer
            ORDER BY benutzer.vname ASC
                     , benutzer.nname ASC
                     , verwendung.sw_name ASC)AS foo
      GROUP BY foo.vname
               , foo.nname
               , foo.sw_name) as foo2
where foo2.dauer = (select max(foo3.dauer) 
                    from (SELECT foo.vname
                                 , foo.nname
                                 , foo.sw_name
                                 ,  SUM(foo.dauer) AS dauer 
                          from (SELECT benutzer.vname
                                       , benutzer.nname
                                       , verwendung.sw_name
                                       , verwendung.dauer
                                FROM benutzer 
                                INNER JOIN verwendung 
                                ON benutzer.login = verwendung.login 
                                AND benutzer.pw = verwendung.pw
                                GROUP BY benutzer.login
                                         , benutzer.pw
                                         , verwendung.sw_name
                                         , verwendung.dauer
                                ORDER BY benutzer.vname ASC
                                         , benutzer.nname ASC
                                         , verwendung.sw_name ASC)AS foo
                          GROUP BY foo.vname
                                   , foo.nname
                                   , foo.sw_name) foo3
                    where foo3.vname = foo2.name 
                    and foo3.nname = foo2.nname 
                    and foo3.sw_name ) foo.sw_name)
```

And depending on what your database is the query can be little bit different...

Comment: oh okey I see...
should have been clearer with my question. I'll edit this.
I want to get those entries of the table which have the max value in the "dauer" column.
For expample:
For Ada should be Ada - Lovelace - Presmaker - 910

Comment: @FlorianDrucker I have updated my answer and I am now going so if this is ok then great and if it is not I will try to help tomorrow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple of hours I figguerd it out :

```
SELECT vname, nname, sw_name, dauer
FROM

(SELECT login, pw, sw_name, dauer
  FROM 
    (SELECT sw_hersteller,sw_name, benu.login, benu.pw, sum(dauer) dauer
    FROM benutzer benu, verwendung verw
    WHERE benu.pw = verw.pw AND benu.login=verw.login
    GROUP BY sw_hersteller, sw_name, benu.login, benu.pw
    ORDER BY vname asc, nname asc) AS foo
  GROUP BY foo.login, foo.pw, foo.sw_name, foo.dauer
  HAVING foo.dauer >= ALL(
  SELECT sum(verwendung.dauer)
  FROM verwendung
  WHERE foo.pw = verwendung.pw AND foo.login = verwendung.login
  GROUP BY login, pw, sw_name, sw_hersteller))as faa 
INNER JOIN benutzer b
ON b.login = faa.login AND b.pw = faa.pw

ORDER BY vname ASC, nname ASC, sw_name ASC
```

Comment: Great @Florian Drucker, happy to hear that. Did my sql worked ? Was it of any help ?